# How do i stop a specific function in JavaScript? I dont want the whole program to stop

Tags: javascript

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'startspam') {
    function spam(){
      msg.channel.send('a')
    }
    setInterval(spam, 2500)
  }
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'stopspam') {
    
  }
});
```

how to stop the function spam ( sorry I'm new to JavaScript and im trying to learn the basics )

Comment: use if else, in your first client. on, so if the user writes startspam it will start a function else if he writes stopspam then nothing to de done

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clearInterval function on the number that setInterval returns to stop the interval. I added some code below to show how that works.

```
var interval = setInterval(someFuntion, 200);
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)

```js
const print = () => console.log('alive');
const intervalId = setInterval(print, 1000);
const stopInterval = () => clearInterval(intervalId);
```

```html
<button onclick='stopInterval()'>Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all java and javascript are not the same..

and for your question -

you can use this clearInterval().

this function receives the id of the interval you want to stop.
and the interval Function returns a unique number so it can used as ID..

the way you do it is somthing like this :

```js
var intervalID = '';

function startInterVal() {
  intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('Hello')
  }, 1000)
}

function stopInterval() {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="startInterVal()">Start</button>

<button onClick="stopInterval()">Stop</button>
```

hope i helped you :)

Comment: @mplungjan now it's fine ?

Answer (score 0):

Also I would move the statement

```
function spam(){ 
   msg.channel.send('a') 
}
```

outside your current code OR change to an anonymous function:

```
 tId = setInterval(function() { msg.channel.send('a') }, 2500)
```

and have tId as a global variable so you can `clearInterval(tId)` to stop it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to stop span function that is called within `setInterval`. This can be done by using `clearInterval`.

Try this:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  var interval;

  function spam(){
      msg.channel.send('a');
  }  

  function start() {
    interval = setInterval(spam, 2500);
  }
  
  function stop() {
     clearInterval(interval);
  }

  if (msg.content === 'startspam') {
    start();
  }
  if (msg.content === 'stopspam') {
    stop();
  }

});
```